# Same property name and primary constructor parameter name in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm little confused how kotlin is managing the property name and the primary constructor parameter name. If I wrote the same property name and the parameter name then kotlin compiler gives an error.

```
class Student(name : String, roll : Int){
    val name: String

    init {
        name = "Asif"
    }
}
```

It gives this error.

```
> Error:(9, 5) Kotlin: Property must be initialized or be abstract
> Error:(12, 9) Kotlin: Val cannot be reassigned
```

But when I change the name of the property `val name : String` or the changing the name of the parameter of the primary constructor `name : String` then the code will work and compile.

This will work or compile fine.

```
class Student(pName : String, roll : Int){
    val name: String

    init {
        name = "Asif"
    }
}
```

What is the reason behind this? Why we can't have the same primary constructor's parameter name and the property name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primary constructor parameters are available in property initializers and initializer blocks (this is what makes the primary constructor special).

In your `init` block, `name` refers to the constructor parameter, which as all other function parameters, cannot be reassigned. This is the second error. The first one is for the same reason, now your property isn't initialized anywhere.

If you want to initialize your property, you can still refer to it as `this.name`:

```
class Student(name : String, roll : Int){
    val name: String

    init {
        this.name = "Asif"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Init block provides parameters from the default constructor. To assign `name` field of your object, you have to explicitly use `this.name`:

```
class Student(name : String, roll : Int){
    val name: String

    init {
        this.name = "Asif"
    }
}
```

But more kotlin-way is to declare field with default value directly in the constructor:

```
class Student(val name : String = "DefaultName", roll : Int){ }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided by others but to clarify look at these versions: 
**(a)**

```
class Student1(name : String, roll : Int){
    val name: String

    init {
        this.name = "Asif"
    }
}
```

**(b)**

```
class Student2(name : String, roll : Int){
    val name: String = "Asif"
}
```

**(c)**

```
class Student3(val name : String = "DefaultName", roll : Int)
```

Classes `Student1` and `Student2` are totally equivalent but `Student3` is not:  
 If you run the below code:

```
val s = Student1("Nick", 2)
println(s.name)
val s2 = Student2("Nick", 2)
println(s2.name)
val s3 = Student3("Nick", 2)
println(s3.name)
```

you will see:

```
Asif
Asif
Nick
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin provides concise and easy way like below:

```
class Student(var name : String, roll : Int){

    init {
        name = "Asif"
    }
}
```

***Copied:*** In fact, for declaring properties and initializing them from the primary constructor, Kotlin has a concise syntax. **[Refer here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html)**